# Beamer. How to put bullet lists inside a {?

Tags: beamer, itemize, enumitem, bullets

I would like to obtain this
[image]

The mwe is: (inside a beamer code)

```
\section{Marco Teórico}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Marco Teórico}
$$
\begin{array}{l}
   \left\{
   \begin{array}{l}
     \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]\mbox{Modelo Van Hiele}\\
     \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]\mbox{Modelo Vinner}\\
     \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]\mbox{Modelo Duval}
   \end{array}   
     \right\{  \\
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball] \\
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
\end{array}
$$
\begin{itemize}%[<+->]
  \item Modelo Van Hiele
  \item Modelo Vinner
  \item Modelo Duval
  \item Visualización y Representación.
  \item Obstáculos al aprendizaje geométrico.  % TrasItem <5-|alert@5>
\end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: You're a member of TeX.SX for about three years and still have not learnt to provide a MWE? :-( And don't use `$$...$$`)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I still don´t know what TeX.SX is! ;-) and I can´t understand what you tell about $$...$$. Sorry

Comment: In principle you could just use the macro for the bullet symbol for the first situation, but I think there should be a better strategy...

Comment: @MikaIke: `$$...$$` is deprecated old syntax! Use `\[....\]` which is robust meanwhile

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very much. In the next weeks I would like to view any documentation about old style, in syntaxx and in packages. In packages are any post, and... in styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\myitem}{
    {\leavevmode \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item} \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}~~}
}

\begin{document}

    \frame
    {
        \frametitle{Marco Teórico}
        \begin{equation*}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
        \begin{array}{l}
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{l}
            \myitem \mbox{Modelo Van Hiele}\\
            \myitem \mbox{Modelo Vinner}\\
            \myitem \mbox{Modelo Duval}
        \end{array}   
            \right\{        
        \end{array}
        \end{equation*}

        \begin{itemize}
         \item Modelo Van Hiele
         \item Modelo Vinner
         \item Modelo Duval
         \item Visualización y Representación.
         \item Obstáculos al aprendizaje geométrico.
                \end{itemize}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]